# How to customize .cshrc to configure command prompt?

Tags: prompt, csh

## Background

Inspired by [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12335/how-to-customize-bashrc-to-configure-command-prompt), I wanted to try to change my command prompt in this manner

1. Enter this line into ~/.cshrc

   a. `setenv PS1 "\[\e[32m\][\[\e[m\]\[\e[31m\]\u\[\e[m\]\[\e[33m\]@\[\e[m\]\[\e[32m\]\h\[\e[m\]:\[\e[36m\]\w\[\e[m\]\[\e[32m\]]\[\e[m\]\[\e[32;47m\]\\$\[\e[m\] "`

   b. I used setenv because it is [the csh equivalent of export](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368944/what-is-the-difference-between-env-setenv-export-and-when-to-use) and is the closest thing to [this procedure](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/), which uses the bash command export.
2. Source ~/.cshrc

However, this did not work. setenv threw the error:

> Variable name must contain alphanumeric characters.

## Question

How do I change my cshell prompt to modify the colors and what text is displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `csh` or `tcsh`, the *environment variable* `PS1` is meaningless: the prompt is actually configured using a *shell variable* named `prompt`.

So the syntax you'll need is:

```
set prompt = "your prompt string here"
```

Also, the list of prompt formatting sequences is different: for example, while `bash` uses `\[`...`\]` to indicate sequences of non-printing characters, `csh` might not have an equivalent at all, and `tcsh` uses `%{` ... `%}` instead.

Google can find you a lot of `tcsh`-specific examples, like [this question here on Unix&Linux.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4317/258991) and [this very well commented example](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~srhuang/teaching/code_snippets/prompt_color.tcsh.html). [This might be helpful too.](http://www.nparikh.org/unix/prompt.php)